# Axios GET with params request shows NULL in Laravel

Tags: laravel, http, laravel-5, axios

I am sending some data to my laravel controller using axios get request but the laravel controller shows request null.

**my axios request:**

```
const data = {
    machine_id: machine_id,
}

const api = "http://192.168.0.108:8000/api/"
const params = JSON.stringify(data)
const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
axios.get(api, { params: params }, headers).then((response) => {
    consoleLog("response", response.data)
})
```

controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   dd($request->all()); // shows null

}
```

If I return the response instead of dd() it shows me something like below image:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   return $request->all(); // shows data

}
```

[image]

How can I catch the data in controller??

Comment: you can  use `$request->vendor_id` to get params from your request

Comment: tried but no luck @MortadaJafar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you. This is what I've done to resolve my problem

```
let config = {
               headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               } 
          }

let params = new UrlSearchParam();
    params.append('var1', 'val1');
    params.append('var2', 'val2');

//Finally

axios.post('gotourl', params, config).then( ( response ) => {
      console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but unfortunately not working. Now instead of data the params are showing in config > _searchParams: Array() .. Please help